# $C^k$ norm for functions of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For a function $f$ of single variable, its $C^k$ norm can be of the form
$$|f(x)|_{C^k}=\sup_{0\leq i\leq k}\sup_x|f^{i}(x)|.$$

What does the usual $C^k$ norm look like for a function of several variables? Say $f(x,y)$, for instance. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's what you would probably guess: 
$$\|f\|_{C^k}=\max_{i,j\ge 0, \ i+j\leq k}\sup_{x,y}\,\left|\frac{\partial^{i+j} f}{\partial x^i\partial y^j}\right|$$
although some people prefer to have the sum over $i,j$ instead of $\max$. In $n$ variables you consider all partial derivatives indexed by $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ such that the *norm* of the *multi-index* $\alpha$ does not exceed $k$: $|\alpha|=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j\le k$.